# catalog_product_load_before event gives getRequestedRouteName() error

Tags: magento-1.9, module, event-observer

I am trying to add an event observer to run before product page load. I am receiving an error.

Here is my `config.xml`

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <product_load_handler>
                        <class>hsc_pce/observer</class>
                        <method>productLoadHandler</method>
                    </product_load_handler>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_load_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Here is my observer function

```
public function productLoadHandler(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    echo 'foobar';
    return;
}
```

I receive the echo and this error

> foobar
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function getRequestedRouteName() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php on line 226

The echo demonstrates that the function is being called. Error occurs without echo as well. If I `die()` before return I do not receive the error, so it's happening afterwards.

The error is in a line that is part of the `getFullActionName($delimiter='_')` function, which is called by the `dispatch($action)` function.

I've tried digging deeper, leading me to alter the `request` object, but it's clear that it's leading nowhere and is not the appropriate solution.

What is causing this error, and how can I prevent it?

**Update**

`Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRequestedRouteName()` shows that the requested route name is 'catalog'.

Answer (score 2):

I was mistakenly extending my observer. It was causing this issue. I had this.

```
class HSC_PCE_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
```

I changed it back to this.

```
class HSC_PCE_Model_Observer
```

Comment: @AmitBera I can't accept my answer for two days. That's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can  get `getRequestedRouteName()` value from `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php`

Because of it, function of class `Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http`.

In order to get `getRequestedRouteName()` value should try with `$action->getRequest()->getRequestedRouteName()`

At all place of web section at magento,you can try:

> ```
> Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRequestedRouteName()
> ```

Comment: I don't understand what solution if any you are offering here. `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRequestedRouteName()` does show that the requested route name is 'catalog'. Knowing this doesn't directly prevent the error.  How can I get the Varien Action Controller to understand this? I will update my question with this information, thanks.

Comment: can u please tell me why getRequestedRouteName value need?

Comment: My module is not running with `getRequestedRouteName()`. It is being run in the core. I am not touching the core.